# Aplicación de Windows en Linux con WINE

Tags: vb.net, .net, linux

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en vb.net y deve.xpress que utiliza una cámara, escaner y un lector de huellas.

Sin embargo, al correrla en openSuse, usando WINE, la aplicación no puede leerlos.

¿Conocen alguna forma de poder utilizar esos dispositivos (algún servicio en java o app en java u otro lenguaje para poder interactuar con los dispositivos)?

Espero me puedan apoyar o darme ideas de como resolver ese gran detalle.

Comment: Hola @JesusR. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías contarnos un poco que intentaste hasta ahora? ¿La idea es programarlo o estás buscando recomendaciones de librerías de terceros? Te comento que en el sitio se busca que las preguntas no busquen opiniones y con una posible respuesta concreta. Quizás te interese realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: la verdad veo dificil ejecutar una aplicacion .net en linux, ya que requieres el framework de .net para que eejcute, nunca escuche que wine lo permitiera. Quizas debas instalar una maquina virtual con windows que use linux de host, entiendo que las virtuales pueden acceder a los dispositivos de la pc host

Comment: Hola. _La aplicación no puede leerlos_ no es una muy buena descripción de lo que pasa. ¿se está generando una excepción? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error en cada caso específico? ¿si no hay excepción, entonces, cuál es el comportamiento? ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Que yo tenga entendido, [Mono](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proyecto_Mono) es un proyecto de codigo fuente aberto la cual, de una cadena de herramientas permite a desarrolladores crear aplicaciones bajo .NET en Linux y en diferentes sistemas operativos, Podrias hacer un proyecto en Mono, e ir probando que cosas van y que no van, lo que si me tiene un poco preocupado, es que las librerias de DevExpress son pura nativas para .NET que se utiliza en Windows, entonces puede que tengas problemas de compatibilidad en Linux por ese lado, de lo contrario, animate a probar a Mono y nos cuentas :D

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que no estas en una maquina virtual, WINE te puede instalar automaticamente mono (parecido a .net) y navegador de internet, la utilizacion de camara web es posible ya que linux lee el identificador de hardaware (posiblemente USB), es posible que linux si haya detectado el scanner y el detector de huellas pero quizas no tenga los controladores adecuados, lo que hace WINE es pasar estos mismos al nivel de interprete de windows, en donde corre tu programa .net, a este nivel practicamente si wine no puede manejarlo, seria necesario que le proporciones los "drivers" para poder manejar el hardware, creo que podrias probar instalando los instaladores de dichos dispositivos en tu wine e intentar nuevamente, suerte